# Centering 2 different layouts in a xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm having a difficult time trying to center my 2 linear layouts. The first linear layout makes the country code picker and edit text on the same line. The second Linear layout is **suppose** to put the button under the first linear layout. But if I ever put the button under the first linear layout it's not going to be centered anymore.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/ghostWhiteColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">


        <com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
            android:id="@+id/ccp"
            android:layout_width="86dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:ccp_showFullName="false"
            app:ccp_showNameCode="false"
            app:ccp_showPhoneCode="true" />

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/register_password"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_phone"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            app:met_floatingLabel="normal"
            app:met_helperText="Enter your phone number."
            app:met_helperTextAlwaysShown="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <com.rey.material.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/button_register_accept"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:background="@color/holo_blue_light"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="50dp"
            android:text="@string/btn_accept"
            android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Example of something not centered.
https://puu.sh/yruSe/0721745d0b.png

Comment: could you put a screenshot of what you want?

Comment: @diegoveloper Updated current thread of an example of something not centered.

Comment: ok check my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your parent layout from this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/ghostWhiteColor"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

To this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this :)
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ghostWhiteColor"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp">


            <com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
                android:id="@+id/ccp"
                android:layout_width="86dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                app:ccp_showFullName="false"
                app:ccp_showNameCode="false"
                app:ccp_showPhoneCode="true" />

            <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                android:id="@+id/register_password"
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
                android:hint="@string/hint_phone"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                app:met_floatingLabel="normal"
                app:met_helperText="Enter your phone number."
                app:met_helperTextAlwaysShown="true" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <com.rey.material.widget.Button
                android:id="@+id/button_register_accept"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:background="@color/holo_blue_light"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/btn_accept"
                android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```